# lightspark in Firefox doesn't show up

Tags: firefox, flash, plugins

I have installed LightSpark Flash Player alternative from what is called the official PPA: https://launchpad.net/~sparkers/+archive/ppa (I mean, I added this repository and then sudo apt-get install lightspark).

But Firefox doesn't feel it. It looks exacly like when I hadn't installed LightSpark. In "Firefox -> Addons -> Plugins" there is no new entry.

What should I do to really use Lightspark after installing it?

Comment: Nope, the lightspark plugin does NOT work in Firefox on Ubuntu, at least not on Facebook flash apps. I now use the chromium-browser to play poker on FB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install lightspark flash in Ubuntu:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sparkers/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

For 13.10

Do this.  Ensure that universe is included in your software resources and, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-lightspark
```

You'll need to restart your browser

Also you can check out [Ubuntu Packages](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/lightspark-common_0.7.2-2_i386.deb.html), to manually install using a .deb file.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 12.XX it is no longer necessary to add the extra repository. Simply installing does the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

You'll need to restart your browser. Then, it should work fine.